# How to determine the coefficient of a geometric progression

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to determine a list, but I'm finding it difficult:

I need a list with the following characteristic:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a=1.45;b=a*x;c=b*x;d=1;
list={a,b,c,d}
```

> $\left\{1.45,1.45x,1.45x^2,1\right\}$

What would be the value of x?

Comment: It is valid for all x. Change the last line to: `list[x_] = {a, b, c, d}`

Comment: This appears to be more of a math question than a Mathematica question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is you use the [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) function:

```
Last[Solve[1.45x^3==1,{x}]]/.Rule->Set;
NestList[#1x&,1.45,3]
```

> $\{1.45,1.28109,1.13185,1.\}$